# How to do load balancing like activity in Azure Data factory because Web API cant handle too many request

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In for each loop activity , I am using Web activity to call Web API depending upon the number of files inside a folder in blob container. 
For example, If I have 5000 files, I use metadata activity to get file names and send the output to for each loop activity to call the web api for each filename, so it calls 5000 times. But the API can handle only few request for certain duration and takes few minutes to process single request.

In for each loop activity though it is synchronously called , but actually the web API cant process so many request in short duration and it looks asynchronous

My idea is to use load balancer like activity, so that next request be processed if one request is finished.

Is there any other way to do it using some other activity?

Comment: Are you saying the Web Activity is not behaving synchronously?  Or are you saying that it is, but the whole process takes too long serially since the API can process like 5 calls at a time?

Comment: yes, if API can process 5 calls at a time, then other 500 calls  is pending during the processing of former 5 calls(foreach loop will be running and calls the web API). The duration of processing each call can vary.